# nginx load balancer - Docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a simple flask app running on port 5000 inside the container , and i'm trying to add nginx load balance to scale the app(3 instances)

Here is my `docker-compose` file :

```
version: "3.7"

services: 
    chat-server:
        image: chat-server
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - './chat_history:/src/app/chat_history'
        networks: 
            - "chat_net"

    ngnix-server:
        image: nginx:1.13
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        volumes: 
            - './ngnix.conf:/etc/ngnix/nginx.conf'
        networks: 
            - "chat_net"
        depends_on: 
            - chat-server

networks: 
    chat_net:
```

And here is my `nginx.conf` file :

```
events { worker_connections 1024;}

http {
    upstream app {
        server chat-server_1:5000;
        server chat-server_2:5000;
        server chat-server_3:5000;

    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }
}
```

both services are on the same `chat_net` network , but when i hit `localhost:8080` on my browser im getting the nginx default page , why is that? what am i missing ?

Comment: Who/how it resolve `chat-server_1`? I guess is just `chat-server:5000`

Comment: I guess they run on a single machine, then how can the 3 chat-servers listen on the same port 5000?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a typo and are not mounting in your `nginx.conf` file correctly.

You spell it `ngnix` in a couple of places in your volumes section and the container runs with the default config (hence default home page).

Once you fix that, you will probably hit the error mentioned by @Federkun (*nginx* won't be able to resolve the 3 domain names you're proxying).

You also have your `server` directive in the wrong place (it needs to be within the `http` section).

This should be the modified version of your file:

```
events { worker_connections 1024;}

http {
    upstream app {
        server chat-server:5000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice this is better than needing `nginx` to be aware of the replica count. You can run `docker-compose up` with `--scale chat-server=N` and resize at anytime by running the same command with a different `N` without downtime.

Comment: Could I just use `proxy_pass http://chat-server:5000;` instead of defining app explicitly as an upstream server?

Comment: @Jedi Why is it better to let docker compose do the load balancing instead of relaying on nginx for that job. With nginx as a load balancer you have better strategy like `least_conn` instead of the round robin that docker provide.

Comment: With docker-compose I'm typically prototyping and don't need intelligent routing (would rather just scale out horizontally). Even in a chat server with skewed connection counts due to keepalives.

Comment: If there are cases where you need specific nginx features, you may have to rethink how you deploy copies of the service (you may not be able to use docker-compose replicas naively and have to do some smart bootstrapping). My answer is more for the common case and folks could definitely choose to roll their own.

Comment: Once you're statically launching N replicas and updating the conf, you now have downtime when you're scaling in/out you're service as you need to restart nginx with the updated conf. Prefer cattle not pets.

Answer (score 0):

@Jedi
shouldn't be at least below?

```
events { worker_connections 1024;}

http {
    upstream app {
        least_conn;
        server chat-server_1:5000;
        server chat-server_2:5000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30436472)

Comment: `chat-server_1` and `chat-server_2` don't exist as names that the nginx container would know about.