# How to run multiple docker WordPress in one host

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am docker newbie.

I want to deploy multiple wordpress containers on one host. I thought of two solutions, but I don't know if they are the right way.

Solution-1: use wordpress image

```
docker run --name wordpress-1 -dp 8001:80 -e some-database-env wordpress
docker run --name wordpress-2 -dp 8002:80 -e some-database-env wordpress
```

[image]

I think wordpress image contains web server, php, fpm so i can access `http://localhost:8001` when it run.
When I need to expose two services to the Internet with port 80, I need a front-end service (nginx) to forward requests to these two services, is that correct?

Solution-2: use 5.5.0-php7.3-fpm-alpine image

This image is smaller, it just open a port 9000 from fpm. It seems dose not have web server. I try to config nginx with it, but not work.

```
docker run --name wordpress-1 -dp 9001:9000 -e some-database-env wordpress:5.5.0-php7.3-fpm-alpine
```

nginx config

```
    server {
        listen 9993;
        server_name localhost;
        
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # I have try use container's ip, but network not work(ping not recieved)
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
        }
    }
```

Browser display file not found
[image]

And get nginx error

```
2020/09/01 21:26:28 [error] 59036#0: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:9001", host: "localhost:9993"
```

Is solution-1 the right way to deploy multiple wordpress containers on one host?

How to use 5.5.0-php7.3-fpm-alpine image to deploy multiple wordpress containers on one host?

Answer (score 0):

It does not listen on that IP address, so change IP address from:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
```

to:

```
fastcgi_pass 172.17.0.1:9001;
```

IP address `172.17.0.1` is an IP address gateway of docker container network.

Or change to :

```
fastcgi_pass ip_address_of_wordpress_container:9001;
```

Comment: I use `docker insepect wordpress` to find out the ip of container and set to nginx, now i get 502 bad gateway error.

Comment: what is error Nginx log  ? are you sure nginx configuration is working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Just continue with your first option and set up NGINX as load balancer, and have config like:

```
http {
    upstream app {
        server wordpress-1:80;
        server wordpress-1:80;
    }
}
```

And to make it more easy, use docker-compose.

Ref - [nginx load balancer - Docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022033/nginx-load-balancer-docker-compose)

Comment: This solution will fail horribly when the two containers are meant for different domains, e.g. first one is set up for example1.com, while the other one is set up for example2.com. You'd then need to let the nginx reverse proxy forward depending on the host.

Comment: Why you would like to have balancer serve different domains? To solve load balancing inside of one domain use two hosts. To serve multiple domains, use instance of balanced  hosts for each domain.